# Image stretched when set as background in the Relative layout

Tags: android, image, android-relativelayout

I am capturing image from camera and sending it to the server .I am displaying the captured image in the background of `RelativeLayout` using the following code:

```
private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
    // Checking whether captured media is image or video
    if (isImage) {
        Log.e("Preview Media", "Called");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        //options.inScaled = false;

        Log.e("File URI", String.valueOf(fileUri));

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
        //Uploading image to server
        new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        Log.e("DownSizing image", "Called");
        Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        Log.e("DrawableN", String.valueOf(dr));
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
    }
}
```

Inside the code ,I am downsizing the image to avoid `OutOfMemory Exception`.While setting the image in the `background` of Relative Layout ,image got stretched.Screenshot is given below:

[image: Stretched Image]

**XML code:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding10">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10"
            android:src="@drawable/back_signup" />

        <com.almabay.almachat.circularImageView.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/cam"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding10"
            android:background="@drawable/camera1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/status"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin20"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10"
            android:text="Status of user"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:background="@color/divider_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
            android:background="@color/divider_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First Name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ashish" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lastNameProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Kumar" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Birthday"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/birthday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="03 December" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:text="Female" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                android:background="@color/while_color"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding10"
                        android:text="Status"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:text="Displaying the status message here" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                android:background="@color/while_color"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:text="Email ID" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                android:background="@color/while_color"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding10">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="Phone"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:text="13464646466" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help to fix the issue.I am using width as match_parent and height as 150dp for the RelativeLayout.

Comment: instead of setting it as a background, put it inside a imageview.

Comment: I cannot use an image view as you can see in the relative layout i am using an arrow,camera, User Name and his status.I am compelled to the the image in the background.You can guess the complexity from the screenshot attached.

Comment: you can set them using relativelayout

Comment: Please check my xml code.I have already used used relative layout to accommodate arrow,cmarea image,username etc.

Comment: Have you tried fitXY?

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" can only be used in image view not in the Relative layout.As you can see using relative layout image got stretched .Relative layout is creating problem for me .Is there any other way to design the page as per screenshot given.

Answer (score 1):

Your RelativeLayout has stable width and height,but your image size doesn't suit so it will stretch.

As your need,the relativelayout should be match_parent,but the height shouldn't be stable,it will be adjusted by your size of image.For example,assume your image size is w width and h height,then your relativelayout height should be adjusted to `screenwidth/width*h.`

**First you can get the image width and height like this:**

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
int w = bitmap.getWidth();
int h = bitmap.getHeight();
```

**then get screenwidth by:**

```
int screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

then calculate scale value:

```
float scaleX = (float) screen_width / w;
```

then calculate layout height:

```
float height = scaleX * h;
```

At last set the height value we got as relativelayout's height:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height;
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

then set the image as its background:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

There is an example in [mygithub](https://github.com/mingyangShang/JiemiMoShengRen/blob/master/src/com/levelup/jiemimoshengren/ui/LoginActivity.java).it has many similar implements like you.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can i check the image size?Actually my problem is that I am capturing the image through camera and posting it to server using Multipart .I am getting the uri of that image and setting it in the background of relative layout .So i don't know the height and width of image in advance.

Comment: As you can see i am compelled to set the image in the background of Relative Layout .Relative Layout is accommodating the view for arrow,name,status etc.

Comment: @DeepakR,if you don't want image to be stretched and relativelayout's height be changed,I think it's impossible,because the image maybe unsuitable for your layout.I see your relativelayout,your view is placed by relative,so I think it won't have many changes when you change the image layout.

Comment: Then please suggest me how to implement the required design .

Comment: what does you mean **required design**?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot,I have to set an arrow ,camera ,username and user status on the image of user.As i am using relative layout here in which i am using an image view for arrow,an image view for camera ,text view for Name and another text view for status.I am setting the profile pic of user in the background that got stretched .Is there any other way to design the above mentioned concept .

Comment: I know your concern,but since you use RelativeLayout to wrap your view ,like TextView for view and so on,these views will auto layout when the RelativeLayout's layoutParams is reset,so your layout won't change too much>I suggest you try my solution,is any problem,welcome to attach me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. view.setLayoutParams(params); Please tell me here which view you are referring to in your code.

Comment: I have used your code but it is not working for me properly as i need a specific height of my relative layout for example 150 dp here in my case.After using your code image is not stretched but is occupying the complete area of my screen .Other views are not shown here

Comment: @DeepakR,then I suggest you decode and compress your image according your required width and height.Here is my [example](https://github.com/mingyangShang/JiemiMoShengRen/blob/master/src/com/levelup/jiemimoshengren/ui/LoginActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/abc"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:contentDescription="image for user"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:src="@drawable/ur_img" >
</ImageView>
```

Set the scale type to fitCenter, it will way may resolve your stretching of image, i also used this in my app to make image normal.

Comment: Please view my problem first .I am adding different views in Relative Layout.So i am compelled to set the image in the background of relative layout.U can check the screen shot.

Comment: @DeepakR a quick fix can be that you make a linear layout for image only and put it as the top element of parent Relative layout, inside that linear layout make imageView and set its scale to adjust image accordingly